# CSS - Formatting a Navigation div beside multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I designed my site so that a navigation bar spans down the whole site. It is handled in a div. The rest of the site is inside divs as well, and will be placed beside the navigation div.

After placing the first div beside the navigation div, everything worked out. When I tried to add a second div beside the navigation div and under the first div, it goes outside of the body. I can I **fix** this?

**THE ORANGE BORDER DIV IS THE ONE I AM TRYING TO FIX**

[Here is my site](http://willhoule.uphero.com/site/)
: **JSFiddle** would be to large and hard to understand, so please use the console in your browser to help me out.

## firstBox is the div that isn't working how I want it to. #navigationPane and #topBox are in the right position

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stellar.js/0.6.2/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
            function dBug(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
            dBug("document ready");

            $.stellar();

        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            width: 1000px;
            min-height: 800px;
            max-height: 1200px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            font-family: Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            border: solid green 1px;
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 10px;
            color: white;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        p {
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #small {
            font-style: italic;
            font-size: 10px;
            margin-top: -12px;
        }

        #topBox {
            height: 400px;
            width: 929px;
            border: solid blue 1px;
            float: right;
            margin-top: -1px;
            margin-right: -1px;
            background-image: url(image.jpg);
            background-size: 1400px 600px;
            background-position: -0% 60%;
            cursor: default;
        }

        #firstBox {
            height: 400px;
            width: 928px;
            border: solid orange 1px;
            float: right;
            cursor: default;
        }

        #navigationPane {
            width: 70px;
            margin-left: -1px;
            border: solid red 1px;
            min-height: 1200px;
            max-height: 2000px;
            margin-bottom: -1px;
            margin-top: -1px;
            background-color: purple;
        }

        #box {
            width: 500px;
            height: 150px;
            border: dotted white 2px;
            clear: none;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
            margin-left: 200px;
            margin-top: 120px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        #navigationPane img {
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        a:hover {
            opacity: 0.8; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topBox" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.2">
        <div id="box" >
            <h1>WH Programming</h1>
            <p>Will Houle Programming - Student Developer</p>
            <p id="small">A site created to host tutorials, past lab assignments, and future endeavors.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="navigationPane">
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/will_houle" title="Twitter"><img src="twitter.png" /></a>
        <a href="http://mediastudies.humber.ca/programs/diplomas/advanced/game-programming.html" title="Humber Program"><img src="humber.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <div id="firstBox">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*I know the coding is very unorganized, but for now this is what im working with*

Comment: paste your code in your question

Comment: It would be very helpful, for us as well as you, if you could isolate the code causing the problem and include that in your question. You may find the issue while doing so, but it will help debugging tremendously.

Comment: added the full code, pointed out which id's are the problematic ones @Annisaini

Comment: above comment @ssube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add some css property which is useful for you?

however, let me tell you. you should use `position` and `top` property for the box which is going out of thr body.

here is that code:

```
<div id="firstBox" style="
    position: relative;
    top: -800;"></div>
```

## or

in your #firstdiv of css stylesheet add these two:

```
position: relative;
top: -800;
```

Comment: and i dont think that you have tried everything. and bythe way have you searched this on internet?

Comment: thanks works for me, and I did look but nothing I typed in worked properly

Comment: should i explain you this. well actuall there is more easy way to so this. but that would disturb other elements. Should i tell you about why i used this?